# How does -7 % 3 = 2, -13 % 3 = 2 or -1 % 3 = 2 exactly behaves under the hood? Ruby

Tags: ruby, modulo

I was curious what is the formula for `negative number % positive number` or vice versa. Ruby

```
-7 % 3 = 2

-13 % 3 = 2

-1 % 3 = 2
```

Thank you

EDIT:

the formula for  `%` operator -> `x-y(x/y).floor`

So `-13 % 3 = -13 - 3 * (-13/3).floor`

then `-13 % 3 = -13 - 3 * -4.33.floor`, and here is critical that .floor "flooring down" to lowest value as ***tadman*** said, which would turn `-13 / 3 = -4.33.floor` to `-5`(because its next lowest point). Unlike with `13 / 3 = 4.33.floor` to `4`.

okay, then `-13 % 3 = -13 - 3 * -5`

then, `-13 % 3 = -13 + 15`

output `-13 % 3 = 2`

Comment: It's just the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). That's one of the rounding interpretations.

Comment: I know how 5 % 2 behaves, but I was surprised to see weird outcomes when it comes to -1 % 3 == 2. If you could expand on that -> much appreciated

Comment: It effectively means it's 2 off of the target of -3 where `-3 % 3 == 0`. Negative numbers count down in Ruby. It's a byproduct of rounding down to the next lowest value.

Comment: `-13 / 3 = -5` and  `-13 % 3 = 2` → `-5 * 3 + 2 = -13`